# numpy conditional operation between 2d and 3d array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing

I am currently working on a project in Python 3.6 with numpy version 1.19.4.
I have a piece of code which worked in Numpy version 1.18.1.
The code is supposed to take an grayscale Image and turn it into a rgb image.
Furthermore it is supposed to set certain pixels to red, based on a threshold of the grayscale image.

```
    pred_rgb = np.stack((pred_img,) * 3, axis=-1).astype(np.float16)
    pred_rgb[pred_img > display_threshhold] = [255, 0, 0]
```

The first line extends the 2d grayscale Image into an 3d rgb Image (which still works fine).
The Problem occurs in the conditional operation, due to pred_img and pred_rgb having different shapes.
I know a few workarounds for this issue, such as treating each dimension individually.
I assume that there is an easier intended option though, do you have any ideas?
Thanks in advance,
Silas

Comment: The code you have written should work. Can you please share the exact error message you are getting? Also please print the shape of the `pred_img` and `pred_rgb` arrays. Also is `display_threshhold` a scalar?

Comment: Ups, just figured it out, display_trhreshold was supposed to be 100, but due to an oversight of me it was None, my bad.  Thanks for your help. P.s. I didnt notice it because the normal debugger wasnt available in that part of the code :"D